# How to prevent leaflet map elements to get focus

Tags: html, leaflet

I have a form and inside the form is a leaflet map. I want to move between elements pressing tab key and I do not want the map or his elements ( buttons ,markers,etc) to get focus. How can I add `tabindex="-1"` to maps controls and  elements to prevent focus, or what I can do to prevent focus?

Here is a jsfiddle to show my scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/LnzN2/2/

```js
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', osmAttrib = '&copy; <a ref="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
       osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib  });

var map = L.map('map').setView([19.04469, 72.9258], 12).addLayer(osm);

var marker = L.marker([19.04469, 72.9258]).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<input type="text" autofocus />
<div id="map"></div>
<input type="text"  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one-shot solution but you can achieve this by disabling each map element in three steps:

1. Disable focus for markers:
   Disable keyboard support for markers by adding `keyboard:false` to the marker element.
2. Add `tabIndex="-1"` attribute to all `<a>` elements located inside `.leaflet-control` divs

   ```
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".leaflet-control a");
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
     elements[i].setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
   }
   ```
3. Disable focus for Close Button inside any open marker popup.

   ```
     var marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
         draggable: true,
         keyboard: false,
         title: "Resource location",
         alt: "Resource Location",
         riseOnHover: true
       }).addTo(map)
       .bindPopup(e.latlng.toString()).on('popupopen',
         function(popup) {
           //disable focus of close button
           var elCloseButton = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-popup-close-button")[0];
           elCloseButton.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
         }).openPopup();
   ```

See my implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/trkaplan/bv763tkf/

Comment: Hi @trkaplan, your solution works great. The only thing I had to change was: var elements = document.querySelectorAll (". Leaflet-control a, .leaflet-container"); to prevent .leaflet-container  get focus too.